# Is there a proven theoretical lowest time complexity for the random generation of a Directed Acyclic Graph?

Tags: algorithm, random, time-complexity, graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs

From my research, I could not find any "standard" (as in widely used) algorithm for the random generation of directed acyclic graphs (acyclic digraphs).

I had to write a random DAG generating algorithm for a JUnit test for a topological ordering algorithm and I was wondering if there is a proven theoretical minimum time complexity that can be achieved for a random DAG generating algorithm.

Comment: random over what distribution?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: You can certainly create a random tree in O(V) time. You could then add additional edges in O(E) time provided that all additional edges connect nodes near the root to nodes farther from the root.

Comment: @AlessandroNerla yeah, sorry that earlier comment was so concise.  Random means: `give_me_a_random_DAG(parameters)` will return a DAG -- one DAG out of the N possible DAGs that it could return, given those parameters.  First, what are the parameters?  (`max_|V|`?  `|V|`? `|E|`?  `expected value and std of |V|/|E|`?)  Second, what are the possible DAGs to be returned?  (are non-connected DAGs valid?)  Third, how likely should it be that you get each DAG from calling this function?  Should each DAG be equally likely? Should isomorphisms be equally likely, or should labelled DAGs?

Comment: Not sure how much detail is needed to answer the question, but without any of it I can say something like "We can generate a random DAG of size `n` in `O(n)` time by generating a random tree, directed from the root"  It's still random, since it's randomly choosing amongst multiple possible outputs, in a manner you can't predict, but it's probably not what you'd expect from a random DAG generator.

Comment: Also, you might get better answers in https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @KevinWang I didn't really think about all the possible details but generating a random DAG in O(n) by generating a random tree is basically the answer I was looking for. Also, thank you for pointing me towards https://cs.stackexchange.com/, I didn't really know about its existence.